# With QClipboard, how can I copy rich text and have it downgrade to plain text for text editors?

Tags: python, qt, copy-paste, pyside

I've got a preexisting function that generates a rich text/html report. My app displays this report in a tooltip. I've added the ability to copy this report to the clipboard using something like the following code:

```
    reportRichText = generateReport()
    clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
    reportRichTextMime = QMimeData()
    reportRichTextMime.setHtml(reportRichText )
    clipboard.setMimeData(reportRichTextMime)
```

This allows me to copy the report and paste it into anything that accepts rich text. For example I can paste the report fine into MS Word. The problem is, however, I cannot paste into a plain-text editor. I simply have a grayed-out "Paste" selection as if there's nothing to paste. Another interesting tidbit, if I do "Paste Special" with MS Word, I only have the option to paste as "HTML Format" no plain text option is listed.

Of course if I simply use QClipboard to copy as plain-text, I can copy-paste wherever I want. However I'm copying/pasting all the markup. Which is obviously what I don't want. I either want rich text or non-marked up plain text.

The behavior I would expect is the behavior you get when you copy/paste text from a web browser. For applications that accept rich text, rich text is pasted in (moreover MS Word will allow you to paste as plain text OR rich text). For plain-text editors the non-rendered plain text is pasted into the plain text editor.

How can I use QClipboard to take Rich-text that can also be pasted as plain text?

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm pretty sure the correct way to do this is to call **both** setText and setHtml on the QMimeData. From the [QT docs for QMimeData](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmimedata.html#setText):

> A single QMimeData object can store the same data using several different formats at the same time

IE if you do:

```
reportRichText = generateReport()
clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
reportRichTextMime = QMimeData()
reportRichTextMime.setHtml(reportRichText)
reportRichTextMime.setText("hello!")
clipboard.setMimeData(reportRichTextMime)
```

then you get:

```
hello!
```

pasted into editors accepting plain-text and my pretty report in editors accepting rtf text. This is because "hello!" is the plain-text representation of the data, while my report is the HTML representation.

For my report, I just decided to go back and figure out a way to generate the report in both HTML and plain text which wasn't as annoying or difficult as I thought it would be. So in effect what I have now is:

```
reportRichText = generateReport(rtf=True)
reportPlainText = generateReport(rtf=False)
clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
reportRichTextMime = QMimeData()
reportRichTextMime.setHtml(reportRichText)
reportRichTextMime.setText(reportPlainText)
clipboard.setMimeData(reportRichTextMime)
```

and this seems to do the trick

Comment: Good to know. From reading the docs it *sounded* like `setText()` set the type of the clip to plain text and `setHtml()` set it to HTML, i.e., that you couldn't use both.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with Qt yet, but from some Googling it looks like you need to subclass `QMimeData` and write your own `html()` and `text()` methods that return HTML and text versions of the data, along with a `formats()` method that returns `text/html` and `text/plain` as the types supported in the object. Then put that on the clipboard.